# Event's setResponse($response) stops logging

Tags: symfony, logging, listener

I'm trying to see errors in log files.
I have an `ExceptionListener` class and a service defined for it with the tag

```
tags:
    - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
```

In the `onKernelException` method if I'm using `$event->setResponse($response);`
the error message will not be logged anymore.

I'm trying to change the response format. This is why I need to do this.
If i remove that `setResponse(),` the error is logged, but as I mentioned, I need it in another format.

Any ideas on how to make it log even with `setResponse` called? 
Can this be done without injecting  `@logger` into my listener?

This is how my listener class looks like

```
class ExceptionListener {

    /** 
     * @param GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event
     */
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $e = $event->getException();

        if ($e instanceof HttpException) {
            $response = new JsonResponse();
             $data = [
                'error' => [
                    'code'    => $e->getStatusCode(),
                    'message' => $$e->getMessage()
                ]
            ];

            $response->setStatusCode($code)
                 ->setData($data);


            $event->setResponse($response);
        }

        // Let the internal listener handle the exception
        return;
    }
}
```

And in services.yml

```
 app.event_listener.exception_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\ExceptionListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
```

Comment: Show us your listener please.

Comment: 1. You can inject `@logger` into your listener and log the exception message `$exception->getMessage()` there. Or 2. Search for `onKernelException` or `setResponse` in http://www.inanzzz.com/ for some examples.

Comment: Calling `setResponse` on an event stops the propagation of that event, so listeners executing after your own will not be called. This is the most probable reason why the exception is not logged. If you still want to use your own response, solution by BentCoder is probably your best bet.

Comment: I've edited my question with listener class and service.yml

Comment: The method suggested here is what I'm using for custom response, but this doesn't log the errors or maybe I'm missing something. http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/5x9m/handling-custom-built-api-exceptions-in-symfony-to-return-standardised-response-body-with-errors